# Error con Crystal Report en ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebBillBarConnectionString1"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena);
        CapaLogica.DataSetBillBar datos = new CapaLogica.DataSetBillBar();

        string sql = "SELECTdbo.factura.fecha, dbo.detalleFactura.numeroFactura, dbo.factura.idCliente,"
        + "dbo.cliente.identificacion, dbo.cliente.nombres, dbo.cliente.apellidos,dbo.detalleFactura.idProducto,"
        + "dbo.detalleFactura.nombre AS producto, dbo.detalleFactura.cantidad,"
        + "dbo.detalleFactura.precio,dbo.detalleFactura.cantidad * dbo.detalleFactura.precio AS subTotal"
        + "FROM dbo.cliente INNER JOIN dbo.factura ON dbo.cliente.idCliente = dbo.factura.idCliente INNER JOIN"
        + "dbo.detalleFactura ON dbo.factura.numeroFactura = dbo.detalleFactura.numeroFactura";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

        adapter.Fill(datos.ReporteFactura);

        CrystalReporteFacturas reporte = new CrystalReporteFacturas();
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
    }
}
```

Tengo esas linea de código y me sale este error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ','.
>
> Línea 22:             SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,
>   con);

ya he revisado y revisado y no doy con el chiste,

Por favor alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta dandole espacio a cada final de cadena, asi:

```
string sql = "SELECT dbo.factura.fecha, dbo.detalleFactura.numeroFactura, dbo.factura.idCliente, "
+ "dbo.cliente.identificacion, dbo.cliente.nombres, dbo.cliente.apellidos,dbo.detalleFactura.idProducto, "
+ "dbo.detalleFactura.nombre AS producto, dbo.detalleFactura.cantidad, "
+ "dbo.detalleFactura.precio,dbo.detalleFactura.cantidad * dbo.detalleFactura.precio AS subTotal "
+ "FROM dbo.cliente INNER JOIN dbo.factura ON dbo.cliente.idCliente = dbo.factura.idCliente INNER JOIN "
+ "dbo.detalleFactura ON dbo.factura.numeroFactura = dbo.detalleFactura.numeroFactura";
```

De esta manera al terminar de concatenar las cadenas no se pegan la terminacion de una con la inicializacion de la otra.

Otra forma de crear la cadena sin tener que utilizar (`+`), seria anteponiendo un (`@`) al crear la cadena, asi:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT
        dbo.factura.fecha, 
        dbo.detalleFactura.numeroFactura,
        dbo.factura.idCliente,
        dbo.cliente.identificacion,
        dbo.cliente.nombres,
        dbo.cliente.apellidos,
        dbo.detalleFactura.idProducto,
        dbo.detalleFactura.nombre AS producto,
        dbo.detalleFactura.cantidad,
        dbo.detalleFactura.precio,
        dbo.detalleFactura.cantidad * dbo.detalleFactura.precio AS subTotal
    FROM
        dbo.cliente
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.factura ON dbo.cliente.idCliente = dbo.factura.idCliente
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.detalleFactura ON dbo.factura.numeroFactura = dbo.detalleFactura.numeroFactura
    ";
```

***Nota:***
Nunca esta demas ejecutar directamente el query en el motor de base de datos, de esta forma siempre evitamos errores de dedos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. ya no me muestra el error, pero igual no me esta mostrando el reporte. me tocara revisar todo nuevamente.